# Does any maven plugins use the <url> tag in the <scm> element in pom?

Tags: maven-plugin

Is the url tag in the scm element in pom used by any plugins or is it's purpose purely informative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used for the Web Access part of the Source Repository page in Maven-generated sites. See for example this page: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/source-repository.html

The corresponding pom file is obviously here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2/pom.xml?view=co&revision=992608&content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: But the plugins don't actual use it, or does it?